# set content type header with rails and apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-3, header, kml

I want to send a generated view as a kml file, with the necessary headers(content-type and file expires in)... the use of head gives a 500, and using response.headers has no effect...

What should i do?

Comment: Can you post your code that attempts to use response.headers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the [`:content_type` option for `render`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-content_type-option).

Comment: The Guides! Damn it, I still live in a dream world where the API docs are useable.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to register the KML mime type. `In your config/initializers/mime_types.rb`

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.google-earth.kml", :kml
```

Then in your action you can do:

```
format.kml { ... }
```

KML Tutorial: http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html#kml_server